# check if not 00000000 or 11111111 or 22222222, etc

Tags: regex

I have problem with one regular expression to check if a (french) phone number is correct.
Phone number must start with one 0 continue with one 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 9 and continue with 8 numbers but theses numbers must not be the same like 00000000 or 11111111...

My current regular expression :

```
/^0(1|2|3|4|5|9){1,1}[0-9]{8,8}/i
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Note that `{n, n}` is the same as `{n}` and you're able to delete `{1,1}` completely as default is "single match".

Comment: as per the regex tag, what language are you using the regex in?

Comment: What about `0122224444` is it valid ? Or `0133333334` ?

Comment: What about numbers starting with `06`, `07` or `08`? You don't want them to be matched?

Comment: @sp00m I agree with you, french phone numbers can start from 01 to 09. `08` are "special" (commercial ones, numéros verts, indigo ...). `09` are reserved to internet providers for VoIP lines.

Comment: 06 and 07 are for mobile phones and i don't want to match them ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/^0[1-59](?!(\d)\1{7}$)\d{8}$/i
```

Some points:

- `{1,1}` is as good as being removed.
- `{8,8}` is as good as `{8}`.
- `(1|2|3|4..)` can be replaced with character class - `[1234]`
- `[12345]` can be replaced by range in a character class - `[1-5]`

The above regex uses negative look-ahead assertion - `(?!(\d)\1{7})` to assert that the 8 digits after first 2, are not all same. If the assertion is true, then it matches the next 8 digits.

- `(\d)` captures the first digit in group 1
- Then `\1` backreferences the captured group to match the same digit that was matched by `\d`
- `{7}` matches the backreference 7 times. That means - `(\d)\1{7}` matches same digit 8 times.

Comment: You were faster so +1, on the other hand don't forget you can change the character class to `[1-59]` :).